# tortoise svn clean up command not working properly

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Hi when i am tried to clean up my code using svn it shows unable to clean up the file which 
  resides on .svn/tmp/xxx.tmp files .

please help me how to resolve my problem with out effecting the other things

Answer (score 1):

Cleanup command from TortoiseSVN deals with some very specific problems when dealing with SVN in general and TortoiseSVN especially, and sometimes is not what you need. Cleanup command makes changes only in .svn folder, and not in your folders.

At this time I can only give some general advice. Point 4) should solve any problem, any time.

1) Try to Update the whole working copy. The problem may just go away.

2) If there are file conflicts you have to resolve them. "Tree conflicts" can't be resolved as easy as regular file conflicts, so for them continue reading.

3) Go to Commit window, and Revert all the files that give you trouble (right-click on file and Revert). If some files have changes that you do not want to be discarded then back those files, and reintroduce the changes after the Revert. CLICK CANCEL IN THE END.

4) Make a completely new working copy (fresh Checkout to another empty folder), and reintroduce all the changes that you may have made from the old working copy.